# Writing bit string '00000000' to binary file outputs incorrect file format

Tags: python-3.x, binary, bit, endianness

I am writing to a binary file 8 bits (big-endian) at a time. The problem that I am having is whenever a sequence of '00000000' is being written to the file, the format of the .bin file is not what I expected

Code snippet:

```py
file = open("example.bin", "wb")
for sample in block:
    file.write((int(sample,2).to_bytes(1, 'big')))
```

Input with correct results:

```
block = ["11000000", "00100010", "01000000", "10000000"]
example.bin: À"@€
```

Input with incorrect results:

```
Input: block = ["11000000", "00100010", "00001000", "00000000"]
example.bin: c022 0800
```

Comment: What did you expect? The 'incorrect' results are correct.

Comment: @orlp i was expecting À"<0x08><0x00>

Comment: It's probably that whatever program you're viewing the file with chooses to display it as hexadecimal. Which should be your default choice when working with binary files anyway.

Comment: @orlp the reason why i'm confused is because i have another .bin file as reference, and when its opened with the same program (sublime), it shows the format in the 'correct' result

Comment: I think, sublime guesses that files with null bytes should be displayed in hex format. There has to be an option to switch between text mode and binary mode in sublime manually. Less sophisticated text editors should always display the "correct" result.